# How to delete the last annotation made on a MapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

```
@IBAction func addPin(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


let location = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
let locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

annotation.coordinate = locCoord
annotation.title = titleTextField.text

var annotationsArray: [[String:Any]]!
var annotationsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "StoredAnnotations")

//If the data is nil, then set the new annotation as the only element in the array
if annotationsData == nil {
annotationsArray = [newAnnotationDict]
} else {
//If it isn't nil, then convert the data into an array of dicts
do {
    //Convert this data into an array of dicts
    annotationsArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: annotationsData!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
    annotationsArray.append(newAnnotationDict)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

}

do {

//Use JSONSerialization to convert the annotationsArray into Data
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: annotationsArray, options: .prettyPrinted)

//Store this data in UserDefaults
UserDefaults.standard.set(jsonData, forKey: "StoredAnnotations")
} catch {
print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

 @IBAction func deleteLast(sender: UIButton){
```

}

I am currently creating annotations on a MapView using the code given above. I would like to delete the previous annotation that was created by the user. How would I do this by using the deleteLast button?

Comment: Try `annotationsArray.removeLast()`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa How would I do this via a button. I tried to make the annotationsArray variable global but the annotations malfunctioned a couple of times... is there another way?